# How to combine this foreach loop into a one line lambda / linq

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, converters

How would I convert the following into a one liner? I know it is possible but I can't seem to think of how again. Possibly using selectmany?

```
    Dim claimIds = allClaimLineItems.Select(Function(i) i.ClaimLineItemId).Distinct()

    For Each id As Guid In claimIds
        Result.ClaimDuplicateItemRuleDataList.Add(GetClaimDuplicateItemRuleDataWithHighestDuplicateFlags(allClaimLineItems.Where(Function(i) i.ClaimLineItemId = id)))
    Next
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = allClaimLineItems
    .Select(i => i.ClaimLineItemId)
    .Distinct()
    .GroupJoin(allClaimLineItems, g => g, i => i.ClaimLineId, (g, matches) => matches)
    .Select(GetClaimDuplicateItemRuleDataWithHighestDuplicateFlags)
    .ToList();
```